# My NLTK code almost does what I need it to, but not quite

Tags: python, nltk, tagging

Code:

```
def add_lexical_features(fdist, feature_vector):
for word, freq in fdist.items():
    fname = "unigram:{0}".format(word)

    if selected_features == None or fname in selected_features:
        feature_vector[fname] = 1

    if selected_features == None or fname in selected_features:
         feature_vector[fname] = float(freq) / fdist.N()
         print(feature_vector)

if __name__ == '__main__':
file_name = "restaurant-training.data"
p =  process_reviews(file_name)
for i in range(0, len(p)):
    print(p[i]+ "\n")
    uni_dist = nltk.FreqDist(p[0])
    feature_vector = {}
    x = add_lexical_features(uni_dist, feature_vector)
```

What this is trying to do is output the frequency of words in the list of reviews (p being the list of reviews, p[0] being the string). And this works....except it does it by letter, not my word.

I am still new to NLTK, so this might be obvious, but I really can't get it.

For example, this currently outputs a large list of things like:

{'unigram:n': 0.0783132530120482}

This is fine, and I think that is the right number (number of time n appears over total letters) but I want it to be by word, not by letter.

Now, I also want it do it by bigrams, once I can get it working by single words, making the double words might be easy, but I am not quite seeing it, so some guidance their would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to `nltk.FreqDist` should be a **list of strings**, not just a string. See the difference:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> uni_dist = nltk.FreqDist(['the', 'dog', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'park'])
>>> uni_dist
FreqDist({'the': 2, 'went': 1, 'park': 1, 'dog': 1, 'to': 1})
>>> uni_dist2 = nltk.FreqDist('the dog went to the park')
>>> uni_dist2
FreqDist({' ': 5, 't': 4, 'e': 3, 'h': 2, 'o': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'k': 1, 'n': 1, ...})
```

You can convert your string into a list of individual words using [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Side note: I think you might want to be calling `nltk.FreqDist` on `p[i]` rather than `p[0]`.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. Can I split into a list of 2 words each with split. I know how to do it with nltk so if not, no problem.